# Is there a way to remove "diverged" message in git?

Tags: git

I accidentally pressed `enter` before I had to which resulted to executing

```
git checkout
```

in some local branch.

Now on `git status` that's what is shown:

```
# On branch <branchname>
# Your branch and 'origin/master' have diverged,
# and have 2 and 329 different commits each, respectively.
#   (use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

Is there any easy way to stop this message from showing?

PS: I don't want to merge yet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git branch --unset-upstream
```

This will stop tracking `origin/master` on the current branch and thus cause the message to disappear. But you might be more interested in an integral solution as provided by @poke.

Comment: Actually you're almost right. For some reason the branche's upstream was changed from `origin/<branchname>` to `master`. I don't have a good explanation on how it happened, but that's what caused that particular message.

Comment: Ok, this wasn't obvious from your initial question. But glad I could help you.

Comment: it wasn't obvious for me too :-) I wouldn't ask if I knew that it was caused by a wrong upstream

Answer (score 1):

Your best option to “get rid” of it would be to work on a separate branch instead of master. This allows you to continue your work however you want, while maintaining a non-diverged branch on your local master itself.

To do that, just call `git checkout -b newBranchName` and you will automatically create a new branch with the current history and switch to it. Afterwards, you could even clean up your local master to “get back” to the master-only history by calling `git checkout master` and then `git reset --hard origin/master`. Note that you should make sure that your working directory is clean first and that your new branch really carries all the history.

Comment: I do work in a separate branch already "I accidentally pressed enter before I had to which resulted to executing ... **in some local branch.**"

Comment: @zerkms Well, what branch does `git status` tell you you are on now?

Comment: @zerkms That’s not really helpful… Are you on master or still on your local branch?

Comment: `On branch <branchname>` (copied from question)